# How to raise/send an event from within the <script> element of SCXML in Qt

Tags: qt, scxml

There is a __Raise() function according to this [reference](https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/OS/latest/Developer/SCXMLRef), that would allow us to raise/send "events" from within the script elements of SCXML using ECMAScript:

> This function is the ECMAScript equivalent to the raise element. It allows an application to raise an event which can be used to direct the execution flow of an SCXML strategy.
>   Usage:

```
__Raise(expr)
__Raise(expr, data)
__Raise(expr, delay)
__Raise(expr, data, delay)
```

But my experiments with Qt’s SCXML module were unsuccessful and the corresponding event would not be triggered:

```
<state id="State_3">
…
<onexit>
    …
    <script>__Raise(‘myEvent’)</script>
</onexit>
</state>
```

Is this function (`__Raise`) supported in Qt’s SCXML module? Or am I doing sth. wrong?

Comment: Read the docs: *Extensions and Deviations
The Genesys SCXML implementation introduces various additions and differences from the W3C SCXML specifications. The following extensions and deviations were introduced to accommodate the needs of the SCXML engine.*

Comment: @ eyllanesc thanks for your reply. so we can not post events from within the script elements of SCXML !!! Is my understanding right?

Comment: I have worked very little with SCXML but what I can point out to you is that if you want to learn Qt SCXML then use the Qt manuals, it also indicates what standard (version) they support, what limitations they have, etc. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscxml-overview.html

Comment: In the first paragraph of the Qt docs they indicate the manuals they use so you should review that information instead of that provided by other companies (which as you can add new features)

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, your answers directed me to right path. Pls post it as an answer so I can mark it a correct.
If I want to raise an event dynamically (&conditionally), I can set a variable in the script element and then use an “if” element with a “raise” element under it to inject the event into the scxml’s event queue (at least this is what I did instead of using  `__Raise()` in the script which is clearly not available in W3C SCXML specification which Qt is based on it; lack of `__Raise()` is a pitty, such a function would have made life easier)